# Defining data annotation using DbContext versus Objectcontext in the database first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

I am using the database first approach with entity framework, when i used to work on the default template the database tables were mapped using the ObjectContext, so i used to create #partial classes & [MetadataType(typeof ) to apply the data annotation ,, but when i start using the Dbcontext code generation template to map the database tables i found that it will create .tt folder in my Model area were i find that **i can apply the data annotation directly to the .cs classes themselves without the need to create partial classes as in objectcontext case**. 
Currently the data annotations are working fine,, **but would my approach cause me problems i am not aware of and i should create partial classes as  i used to do with the Objectcontext** ?
BR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't edit generated code because changes you make will be overwritten on re-generation. This is why most generators emit partial classes.

The best practice for your situation would be to create a new file in your solution with another partial class declaration. In that file, add the [`MetadataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) attribute to the class, and add your property-level validation attributes to the "buddy" class (the one referenced in the attribute). This allows you to use validation attributes on the generated properties and, should your model/database change, you can still re-generate your model classes without losing them.

For example, your new file might look something like:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
partial class Person
{
    // Add logic to the generated class in here.

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
}

class PersonMetadata
{
    // Add attributes to the generated properties in here.

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You point will be valid if i am using ObjectContext, since that template will create model classes and not partial classes as in the DbContext template case. So in the DBContext template if i want to add any helper methods i should do it in the automatically generated partial classes as i canot add helper methods in the metadatatype class so in this way the helper method is added to the automatically generated code and this means i will lose it if i regenerate the code. Any suggestions.BR

Comment: The `MetadataType` is just used to add attributes to already declared properties (since partial properties are not possible). All other helper logic can be added directly to the class via the non-generated file's portion of the partial class.

Comment: i think that the whole partial classes under the.tt folder will be removed and re-created incase i regenerate the code,, i do not know what you mean by "non-generated file's portion of the partial class.",, can u explain this . BR

Comment: @johnG Correct, you shouldn't modify the files under the .tt item. I'm proposing that you create a new file in your solution that contains another `partial class` delcaration. (The prupose of a partial class is to split the class into multiple files.)

Comment: @johnG, I've updated the answer to, hopefully, make things a bit clearer.

Comment: This link helped me a lot, hope it does the same for someone else http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation

Answer (score 0):

Create the same partial classes to define your metadata OR you can simply reverse engineer your existing database using the Entity Framework Power Tools so you have POCO classes. Then you can use the fluent API (you'll see the validations it adds for you) instead of data annotations to give you server side validation.

If you want client side, then you can still apply them to your models, as they wont be regenerated every time you compile .

however - I would recommend you create ViewModels and use AutoMapper to map between your EF objects and viewmodels. Then you can apply your annotations directly to your ViewModels.

Comment: actually what i have noted that the classes under the .tt folder are partial classes by default ,, so this means that if i want to modify the database and recreate the Dbcontext again all the data annotations and helper methods will be deleted ,, so how i can avoid this so all the data annotation and the helper methods will not be deleted even if recreate the Dbcontext again?

Comment: If you use the tt templates then you need to use the partial classes unless you modify the tt templates to add them for you based on the model schema... Or you reverse engineer like I mentioned

Comment: But i can not create the same partial classes to define my metadata , as the visual studio will raise an error that the classes already exsists.

Comment: you can have 5 partial classes with the same name, thats the point of them. You create another partial class that has your MetaDataType attribute. Then create a third class with the data annotations in it. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee256141.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your situation is that you reverse-engineered your Database-First style to a Code-First style.  If your context class inherits from DbContext, you are in Code-First style now (unless there is some strange hybrid possible, which I don't know about!).

In code-first, there is really no point of creating partial classes for data annotations, IMO.

Comment: i used the Dbcontext code generation to map my exsisting tables, then it creats .tt folder containing my tables as classes; so can i apply the client side data annotation to the classes themselves.so i started using Db first apprach and them after the mapping i am in the Code first apprach . BR

Comment: but if i apply the data annotations directly into the classes then i will loss them incase i need to modify the database and regenerate the entity framework classes. BR

Comment: DbContext is not exclusive to the code-first workflow. You can pass an EntityConnection into the constructor to load your metadata from an entity data model instad of building it from code. The [DbContext template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2) enables this.

Comment: but if i apply the data annotations to the automatically generated partial classes then i will lose these definitions if i regenerate the code.

Comment: @johnG correct, the answer I proposed solves this issue. Mathieu assumed that you were using the code-first workflow, but you are not.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Brice ! I didn't know you could use DbContext outside code-first.  Thought that once you used a T4 Template to generate a class with it, you had to delete the .edmx altogether and go on code-first style.  I'm not sure why one would keep the Edmx + T4 templates and use DbContext, though, why not use the EntityContext then?

Comment: @Brice , i think that the whole partial classes under the.tt folder will be removed and re-created incase i regenerate the code,, i do not know what you mean by "non-generated file's portion of the partial class.",, can u explain this . BR